# Calculate shortest distance between a point and line in mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial, spatial

[image]

Suppose I have a line AB as MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605) and a point P as POINT(51.3641917981 2.87673850395) in MYSQL. I want to calculate the shortest distance D between point P and line AB. Please help me regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line, particularly the section entitled "Line defined by two points".

Comment: Why you need to calculate this in MYSQL??

Comment: @avisheks - mysql supports geometry objects, so I don't see the question as unreasonable

Comment: @avisheks I want to sort data through shortest distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure MySQL has the ST_Distance method for ordering by the distance?

```
order by st_distance(geom1, geom2)
```

And for calculating the distance, you can reference this blog:

[MySqlPerformanceBlog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)

It shows how to define a user function (haversine) for making the calculations.